# mysqli error : Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Tags: php

What's wrong with my code?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM allfriend WHERE friendOf = ?");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $userId);

    if($stmt->execute()){
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $result[] = $obj;
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add a variable to an existing object instance as if it were an array:

```
$result[] = $obj;
```

Choose a different name for that array

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $output[] = $obj;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Alternatively, if you don't do anything with `$obj`:

```
$output = $result->fetch_all();
echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

The $result is already used to get the RESULT of the SQL prepared statement.
You have used the same name for your array.
Try to use the name 'output[]'

eg:-

```
 $output[] = $obj;
```